# Animate div on URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-animate

I am trying to write a piece of code that animates a div when a URL is visited. Here's my code:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("index.php") >= 0){

$('#popout-left-menu-container')
.animate(
{
'right':'-3px'
},500
);

};
```

I have tried this but it doesn't animate?

I have the below piece of text which does work when the #open-menu-button id is clicked.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('#open-menu-button').click(
        function(){
            $('#popout-left-menu-container')
                .animate(
                    {
                        'right':'-3px'
                    },500
                    );

        });

        $('#popoutmenuclose').click(
        function(){
            $('#popout-left-menu-container')
                .animate(
                    {
                        'right':'-1500px'
                    },500
                    );
        });

});
```

Comment: Can you post relative CSS?

Comment: Where is that if located? Put it in a `$(document).ready(`

Comment: Where is the code within the page? In the head? Before or after the element you are trying to animate?  Is it wrapped in a `$(document).ready`?

Comment: It is in the <head>, can you show me the code with the $(document).ready added?

Comment: It's the same as in your bottom example... `$(document).ready(function(){...your code here...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the questioner asked to see the implementation discussed in the comments, here it is:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    if(document.URL.indexOf("index.php") >= 0){

    $('#popout-left-menu-container')
    .animate(
    {
    'right':'-3px'
    },500
    );

    };

});
```

Note that the code is similar but will only fire on `document.ready()`.

Comment: @Steve I didn't really copy paste from the comments, rather I was the first to notice the issue if you look at my comment. I put this answer here at the questioner's request.

Comment: Oh my... my biggest apologies... I never saw your comment above.  Mea culpa. :(